# Azure : busy worker role

Tags: azure

I have a Microsoft azure project. In this project I deploy 3 cloud services.
I have 2 different environments, one for the tests and the other one for the production.

I haven't any problem for the deployment on the test environment, but recently it's impossible to deploy one of my services on production.

Here is the error (with visual studio) :

> *11:42:49 - Instance 0 of role Test-Worker is busy
>       Details: Starting role... System was initialized successfully. [2015-04-10T09:42:26Z] Last role error: exit code - 0, exit time -
>   [2015/04/10, 09:42:27.927] 11:44:55 - Instance 0 of role Test1-Worker
>   is busy
>       Details: Starting role... System was initialized successfully. [2015-04-10T09:44:29Z] Last role error: exit code - 0, exit time -
>   [2015/04/10, 09:44:31.401] 11:44:55 - Instance 0 of role Test-Worker
>   is busy
>       Details: Initializing role... System was initialized successfully. [2015-04-10T09:44:47Z] Last role error: exit code - 0, exit time -
>   [2015/04/10, 09:44:49.006] 11:47:03 - Instance 0 of role Test1-Worker
>   is restarting
>       Details: Role has encountered an error and has stopped. System was initialized successfully. [2015-04-10T09:46:45Z] Last role error: exit
>   code - 0, exit time - [2015/04/10, 09:46:47.623] 11:47:03 - Instance 0
>   of role Test-Worker is busy
>       Details: Waiting for role to start... System was initialized successfully. [2015-04-10T09:46:58Z] Last role error: exit code - 0,
>   exit time - [2015/04/10, 09:47:00.230] 11:49:07 - Instance 0 of role
>   Test1-Worker is restarting
>       Details: Role has encountered an error and has stopped. System was initialized successfully. [2015-04-10T09:48:55Z] Last role error: exit
>   code - 0, exit time - [2015/04/10, 09:48:57.005] 11:49:07 - Instance 0
>   of role Test-Worker is busy
>       Details: Waiting for role to start... System was initialized successfully. [2015-04-10T09:48:58Z] Last role error: exit code - 0,
>   exit time - [2015/04/10, 09:49:00.647]*

When I check on the azure console, I can see that indeed my worker instances are busy.

Recently I have updated my azure to sdk2.5, but as it works in test environment I am not sure it is the problem. Any guess ?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure all of the Microsoft provided Azure dlls in your references folder are set to copy local.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have now this message : 6:01:53 - Your role instances have recycled a number of times during an update or upgrade operation. This indicates that the new version of your service or the configuration settings you provided when configuring the service prevent the role instances from running. Verify your code does not throw unhandled exceptions and that your configuration settings are correct and then start another update or upgrade operation.

Comment: Delete the deployment but not the cloud service and try deploying again. If that doesn't work then I think the error message is probably right. Use a text compare tool and compare the local and cloud config files to each other to see if you can spot any important differences. Second, you can always turn on remote debugging. Third, turning on intellitrace for the deployment should get you a cause fairly quickly, but that requires the very expensive Visual Studio Ultimate. I should add that you can see the Windows event logs by using the Azure cloud service diagnostics functionality.

Comment: Also you can add lots of debug.information statements to your code and then look in the Azure diagnostic logs in table storage for the output. Make sure you turn on application tracing and set it to "information" in the Azure diagnostics settings.

Comment: thx for your help, I found the problem with intellitrace ; it was a reference problem in a project

Comment: FYI, in the future you can use the troubleshooting workflow at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx to troubleshoot these types of issues.

Comment: I upgraded from Azure 2.7 to 2.8 and it set the new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime copy local to false. Go figure. Good thing there is StackOverflow, or else we would all be running on Linux.